# Android Publisher Api How to Convert Region Prices with Proper Bounds

Tags: subscription, androidpublisher

I'm wondering if anyone has experience using androidPublisher api to create a subscription and to supply all of the regionalConfigs automatically that fit within the bounds of the regionsVersion.version.

My Example code here:

```
const regionPrices = await this.androidPublisher.monetization.convertRegionPrices({
            packageName: "",
            requestBody: {
                price: {
                    currencyCode: "USD",
                    units: String(units),
                    nanos: nanos ?? 0,
                },
            },
        });

let seenRegionCodes = { US: true };
for (const region of Object.values(regionPrices?.data?.convertedRegionPrices ?? {})) {
            if (!region || !region.regionCode || seenRegionCodes[region?.regionCode]) {
                this.logger.info("Already seen region: ", region.regionCode);
                continue;
            } else {
                seenRegionCodes[region.regionCode] = true;
                regionConfigs.push({
                    newSubscriberAvailability: true,
                    price: {
                        currencyCode: region.price?.currencyCode,
                        units: String(region.price?.units),
                        nanos: region.price?.nanos,
                    },
                    regionCode: region.regionCode,
                });
            }
        }


const subscription = await this.androidPublisher.monetization.subscriptions.create({
            packageName: "",
            productId: subscriptionId,
            "regionsVersion.version": "2022/02",
            requestBody: {
                basePlans: [
                    {
                        autoRenewingBasePlanType: {
                            billingPeriodDuration: "P1W",
                            legacyCompatible: false,
                        },
                        basePlanId: basePlanId,
                        regionalConfigs: regionConfigs,
                    },
                ],
                listings: [
                    {
                        title: `Subscription - ${user.username}`,
                        languageCode: "en-US",
                        description: `Subscription for userId: ${user.id}`,
                    },
                ],
                packageName: "",
                productId: subscriptionId,
            },
        });
```

The problem with this is the `convertRegionPrices` call seems to return nanos and units that are outside of the bounds listed [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13125742?sjid=3155719759202570006-NA). Also it will return some regions that are not billable by Google play. So the call will fail.

Is there a method that we can use that will give me the prices within the bounds? Or do I need to write the logic for the 175 regionCodes manually?